# Hide default browser tooltip using bootstrap or angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

Howe can I hide the Default Browser Tooltip while using Bootstrap tooltip bs-tooltip?

I cannot use plain `JavaScript` or any `css` or `jQuery`. I can only use angular js.

**My code:**

```
a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" bs-tooltip title="Collapse"
```

But this ends up showing both the Bootsrap bubble tooltip as well as the default browser.  If I remove the title nothing appears.

Comment: Every browser? Bootstrap version?

Comment: use data-title instead of title hides the browser default tooltip

Comment: Right, but is not backward compatible to non JS version.

Answer (score 0):

Read more about [Angular - Bootstrap - Tooltip](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)

```
<a href="#" tooltip="This is angular bootstrap tooltip">Link</a>
```

[Tooltip Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/s6GWrDAdDUs2qL4VWGpG?p=preview)